# Payment Gateway for Java

Tags: java, payment-gateway

How to create Payment Gateway using java?

Detailed Description for payment gateway in java (It will helpful for me). I want to integrate with my application.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: -1 this is way too underspecified. It should be closed.

Comment: reinvention of wheel

Answer (score 14):

You don't want (and can't) implement a payment gateway. At least not by asking a question "how to create a payment gateway", and definitely not alone. What you are looking for, perhaps, is to be able to receive payments from customers. You can use an existing payment gateway:

- [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/)
- [MoneyBookers](http://www.moneybookers.com/app/)
- [Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/)
- [WorldPay](http://www.rbsworldpay.com/)

All of them have well-described APIs and web-services to communicate with - just pick one with the best financial options for you and look for its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean integrating with an existing payment gateway (such as PayPal's) then you better read their [official IPN documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro) or a third party tutorial such as [this](http://designertuts.com/paypal-ipn-receiving-instant-payments-in-your-web-application/) (written for PHP but the logic is the same for all languages).

If this is a different payment gateway vendor, you need to find documentation and a tutorial.